# Does a Warlock receive the benefit of their familiar's Magic Resistance trait?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock, familiars

The Warlock has access to special forms for their *find familiar* spell through the Pact of the Chain feature. I'm wondering if these special forms, the Quasit, Imp, and Pseudodragon in particular, allow the player character to share the familiar's Magic Resistance feature. In the Monster Manual each of these creatures has a sidebar that states that the familiar shares its Magic Resistance feature with the companion they are bonded to, but the PHB doesn't mention this in any of the creatures' stat blocks.

For example, in the **Variant: Pseudodragon Familiar** sidebar on page 254 of the MM it says:

> "While the pseudodragon is within 10 feet of its companion, 
>       the companion shares the pseudodragon's Magic Resistance trait."

This feature seems clear in the MM but I'm led to believe that it wasn't intended for Player Characters since mention of it is absent from the stat blocks in Appendix D of the PHB (pages 307-309).

Would a 3rd level warlock who chose one of these familiar forms through the Pact of the Chain feature benefit from *advantage from saving throws from spells and other magical effects* due to these special forms, or was this feature only meant for powerful NPCs and enemy spellcasters who had made this link with these familiars themselves?

Comment: Related: [Why can't the “Variant: Imp Familiar” be found with the Find Familiar spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101217/why-cant-the-variant-imp-familiar-be-found-with-the-find-familiar-spell)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No, a Warlock with the Pact of the Chain feature does not receive Magic Resistance if they choose a Quasit, Imp, or Pseudodragon. In the first place, a variant rule is only in play if the DM chooses. However, even if the DM decides that pseudodragon familiars (for example) are a thing, it still doesn't benefit the Warlock.

> Some pseudodragons are willing to serve spellcasters as a familiar. Such pseudodragons have the following trait.

So "some pseudodragons" will be familiars who share Magic Resistance with their masters. The Warlock, however, gets their familiar from the *find familiar* spell, which says:

> You gain the service of a familiar, a spirit that takes an animal form that you choose: [...]

The Pact of the Chain says that:

> When you cast the spell, you can choose one of the normal forms for your familiar or one of the following special forms: imp, pseudodragon, quasit, or sprite.

In other words, the Warlock's familiar isn't any sort of pseudodragon, let alone one with the variant. It's a spirit that takes the form of a pseudodragon (and can take a different form anytime the Warlock chooses). The spell does say that:

> [...] the familiar gains the statistics of the chosen form [...]

However, the statistics of a creature are defined on pages 6-11 of the Monster Manual. The short definition is that, if you look at a creature's entry, it's everything in the yellow box. This doesn't include variant traits like the Familiar trait - those are in green boxes off to the side.

All of that aside, a generous DM could, of course, allow a Pact of the Chain familiar to provide its master with Magic Resistance. It must be pointed out, though, that this is making the Pact of the Chain vastly more powerful than it normally is, so DMs thinking about it should consider carefully.

An even more generous DM could allow *any* player to gain the service of a creature with the familiar variant. This, too, should be considered carefully - it's effectively giving the player a more powerful version of the Pact of the Chain feature for free.

Comment: I don't have my books handy. Is there anywhere in the language of Pact of the Chain or elsewhere in Warlock that says that the spirit does not in game mechanics essence become the familiar creature in question?

Comment: @Escoce The language you are looking for is in Pact of the Chain where it says the *spell* you are casting to gain your familiar is *'Find Familiar'*.  Of which you would then find the relevant *Find Familiar* spell details and read the following:  "...You gain the services of a familiar, **A spirit** that takes on an animal form you choose....When the familiar dies, it disappears, **leaving behind no physical form**...".  What we are seeing here is that 'Find Familiar' gives you a sentient spirit that must take a physical form for aesthetic purposes so that it can function and aid the caster.

Comment: I am afraid the sentence after the choices also says "and it has the statistics of that creature" or something like that. This in effect makes the familiar from a game mechanics point of view. that creature.

Comment: @Escoce The Familiar variant isn't part of the creature's statistics.

Comment: "An even more generous DM could allow any player to gain the service of a creature with the familiar variant." -- Remember though that this creature is a creature, and if killed would just die (Or in the case of devils go back to the 9 layers), meaning it can't be "summoned" at the cost of an hour and a gold to have it bacl

Comment: This answer asserts that variant traits aren’t considered one of “the statistics of the chosen form” even when that variant is in use. This assertion seems very dubious to me. Can you provide any evidence for it?

Comment: @KRyan - [Why can't the “Variant: Imp Familiar” be found with the Find Familiar spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101217/why-the-variant-imp-familiar-cannot-be-found-with-the-find-familiar-spell)  Here's a better discussion about the different types of familiars.  In that question, there are quotes/rulings from Jeremy Crawford saying that the familiar variants aren't meant for PCs to ever have and that the resistance isn't something a PC warlock gets.

Comment: @J.A.Streich: On top of that, since non-Chain pact Find Familiar couldn't summon such a creature, you'd have to make the arrangement with an existing, living version of said creature. Beyond the whole "could die" thing, it doesn't have any other restrictions/powers from Find Familiar: Unless stated specifically, it isn't necessarily loyal (e.g. never trust a variant quasit familiar), can't share senses or communicate telepathically (though most variant familiars provide something similar), can't be hidden in a pocket dimension and can't deliver touch spells.

Answer (score 1):

These are separate sources which are meant to be read independently of each other.  One familiar is a spirit in a corporeal form and the other is an actual named Fiend, Fey, Dragon, Devil.

**Find Familiar spell states:**

> "... the familiar has the statistics of the chosen form ..." (PHB pg. 240)

**Statistics refers to:**

> A monster's statistics, sometimes referred to as its stat block, provide the essential information that you need to run the monster. (MM pgs. 6 - 11)

**Variant: Familiar (DM Approved)**

> *VARIANT: QUASIT FAMILIAR*
>
> Mortal spellcasters interested in extraplanar familiars find quasits
>   easy to *summon* and eager to serve. The quasit plays the part of the
>   obsequious servant. It serves its master well, but it goads the mortal
>   to greater and greater acts of chaos and evil. Such quasits have the
>   following *trait* (not retained by FF spell).
>
> *Familiar*
>
> The quasit can serve another creature as a familiar, forming a telepathic bond with its willing master. While the two are bonded, the master can sense what the quasit senses as long as they are within 1 mile of each other. While the quasit is within 10 feet of its master, the master shares the quasit's Magic Resistance *trait*(*). At any time and for any reason, the quasit can end its service as a familiar, ending the telepathic bond.

Is about acquiring the *actual* creature by other mean referred to by *summon*.  You would not gain the *Find Familiar* features, like use an action to look through the familiars senses.  And vice versa, *Find Familiar* does not gain *Magic Resistance Trait*

Being this is a Variant ruling for the DM it only applies if the DM allows it.  Otherwise, you are stuck with the *Find Familiar* version.

Lastly, if I'm not mistaken, the lastest version/publishing trumps previous ones with duplicate rulings, ergo MM trumps PHB for stats.  In addition, the DM would / should refer to the MM when he tells / gives you the statistics for said familiar creature form.  You have the option of choosing the form, not the stats.