# Can a Warlock with Pact of the Chain gain Magic Resistance from a Pseudodragon familiar?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, familiars

If a Warlock selects Pact of the Chain, they gain the ability to summon a pseudodragon familiar with Find Familiar.

Pseudodragons have a sidebar in the Monster Manual entitled **Variant: Pseudodragon Familiar**. It reads:

> VARIANT: PSEUDODRAGON FAMILIAR
>
> Some pseudodragons are willing to serve spellcasters as a familiar. Such pseudodragons have the following trait. Familiar. The pseudodragon can serve another creature as a familiar, forming a magic, telepathic bond with that willing
> companion. While the two are bonded, the companion can sense what the pseudodragon senses as long as they are within 1 mile of each other. **While the pseudodragon is within 10 feet of its companion, the companion shares the pseudodragon's Magic Resistance trait**. At any time and for any reason, the pseudodragon can end its service as a familiar, ending the telepathic bond.

This describes a variant ruling where a spellcaster can befriend a pseudodragon and gain the Magic Resistance trait. However, because a warlock summons the pseudodragon directly, it's not clear if this would apply to their situation.

**If a Warlock summons a pseudodragon familiar through pact of the chain, does the Warlock also benefit from the pseudodragon's Magic Resistance trait?**

Comment: Related, discussing the various uses of the word "familiar": "[Why can't the “Variant: Imp Familiar” be found with the Find Familiar spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101217)